# Change String to Decimal Laravel Migration

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, migration

I'm trying to Alter my current table and can do it just fine with a SQL Query in my migration file like this:

```
<?php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('xyz', function (Blueprint $table) {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE mydatabase.xyz CHANGE funding_needed funding_needed decimal(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00 ');
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE mydatabase.xyz CHANGE funding_received funding_received decimal(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00 ');
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('xyz', function (Blueprint $table) {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE mydatabase.xyz CHANGE funding_needed funding_needed varchar(191) NOT NULL ');
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE mydatabase.xyz CHANGE funding_received funding_received varchar(191) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0');
        });
    }
```

But if I do it the this way I get an error:

```
<?php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('xyz', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->decimal('funding_needed', 10, 2)->nullable(false)->default(0.00)->change();
             $table->decimal('funding_received', 10, 2)->nullable(false)->default(0.00)->change();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('xyz', function (Blueprint $table) {          
         $table->string('funding_needed', 191)->nullable(false)->default(false)->change();
         $table->string('funding_received', 191)->nullable(false)->default(0)->change();
        });
    }
```

ERROR:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT '0'
>   NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, CHANGE ' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER
>   TABLE xyz CHANGE funding_needed funding_needed NUMERIC(10, 2)
>   CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL COLLATE
>   `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, CHANGE funding_received funding_received
>   NUMERIC(10, 2) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL COLLATE
>   `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`)

I want to do it the 2nd way due to running this in production. I don't want to modify the production migration to match my production database.

Comment: Don't know about the specific error you're getting, but, I think using NOT NULL and DEFAULT together is redundant. If it has a default value, well is obviously not going to be null, right?

Comment: You are correct. I was only trying to match the SQL Query. If I remove the `nullable(false)` and only keep the defaults it still doesn't run correctly.

Comment: Have you tried passing the argument as a string? 0.00 might not be a valid number in php, "0.00"

Comment: Works as a sting, but not as a decimal. I'm trying to change it from a String to a Decimal

Comment: I meant, `$table->decimal('funding_needed', 10, 2)->nullable(false)->default("0.00")->change();`

Comment: No luck. tried `"0.00"` and `'0.00'`

Comment: What if you breakdown the changes, first do the type change, then add the default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed on this [Github thread](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3714#issuecomment-571998622) for doctrine/dbal package, which is the package you install before you run this update migrations, there's a bug on changing column types.

Using `->charset(null)` along with `->change()` should serve as a workaround in the meantime, as pointed on the link.

Comment: I tried your method a few ways and even tried to simply change `$table->string` to `$table->decimal` I still get error. The full error is updated in my original question.

Comment: So, even if you run the change method by itself you get an error? what error do you get if you only run that part?

Comment: If I run `$table->decimal('funding_needed', 10, 2)->change();` I get the above error in my question.

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3714#issuecomment-571998622

Comment: PWEESH!! `->charset(null)` before change did the trick! Thank you for helping on this. Update your answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

guys, I had trouble to converting `string` to `decimal` and as @echo said in the comments

> `->charset(null)->change();` did the trick!

Thanks, guys for saving my time!